# Content Query Web Part results not synchronized

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-query-web-part

I have a SharePoint 2010 content query web part set up which is querying several lists in a site collection. It is returning the expected data in most cases but 6 out of the 30 or so entries are not synchronized with the data currently displaying in the lists. The page the CQWP is on is not published so I am wondering if this is the cause?

I have flushed the object cache and cleared my browser's cache as well just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CQWP has its own internal caching that can be modified by exporting the web part and editing the DWP file. I think it caches results for 15min. Other then this, the only thing I can think of is that there may be security issues on the items (i.e. current user does not have read access to them) or filter settings that are preventing these values from being shown.

I don't think it has anything to do with the page the WebPart is placed on